# How do I determine a vector x $\in \mathbb R^4$ that satisfies $T(x) = A$

Tags: matrices, transformation

$T$ is a linear transformation

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
2\\4\\8\\
\end{bmatrix}$

How can you define a vector $ x \in \mathbb R^4 $ which satisfies $T(x) = A$

this is just a made up example. Forgive me if it's not valid.

this is homework, so a point in the right direction would be preferred.

Thanks.

Comment: Updated the title and the infos.

Comment: Now it makes sense: first, one would have to find out whether the vector $\;A\;$ belongs to the image of $\;T\;$ at all. Nicely enough, this same procedure, carried on some matrix representation of $\;T\;$,  can also yield a solution $\;x\;$ as wanted.

Comment: Well the assignment before that was. Find the dimension of the subsets ran T and ker T. I think ran is my language version of image

Comment: Ok then. If, for example, you know that Im$\,(T)=\Bbb R^3\;$ then the vector $\;A\;$ , and in fact any other vector, is going to be in the image, but otherwise one has to know what $\;T\;$ is in order to find out whether $\;Tx=A\;$ has a solution

Comment: So ok. I have A*x = b. I know the matrix A, and i know the result b. I just can't figure out how to find the vector x. in algebra it would be x = b/A, but that, I don't know how to translate into the matrix world.

Answer (score 0):

In a matrixe word, $A*x=b$ imply $x=(A^{-1})*b$ if  $A$ is inversible, and the inverse is $A^{-1}$, but you need to make intention on the dimension of $A$, in your example If you considere $T(x)=A$  with your hypothesis $T \in \mathbb{M}_{(3,4)}(\mathbb{R}^4)$ :

\begin{matrix}a_1x_1 + b_1x_2 + c_1x_3 = d_1\\
a_2x_1 + b_2x_2 + c_2x_3 = d_2\\
a_3x_1 + b_3x_2 + c_3x_3 = d_3\end{matrix}

If  :
$A = \begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1&c_1\\a_2&b_2&c_2\\a_3&b_3&c_3\end{pmatrix}$ with $X= \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix}$ et
$b = \begin{pmatrix} 
d_1\\ 
d_2\\ 
d_3
\end{pmatrix}$.
The system admet one  unique solution if an only if  $det(A)\neq 0$  :
$x_1 = \frac{\det(A_1)}{\det(A)} = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}d_1&b_1&c_1\\d_2&b_2&c_2\\d_3&b_3&c_3\end{vmatrix}}{\det(A)}$
$x_2 = \frac{\det(A_2)}{\det(A)} = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}a_1&d_1&c_1\\a_2&d_2&c_2\\a_3&d_3&c_3\end{vmatrix}}{\det(A)}$ and 
$x_3 = \frac{\det(A_3)}{\det(A)} = \frac{\begin{vmatrix}a_1&b_1&d_1\\a_2&b_2&d_2\\a_3&b_3&d_3\end{vmatrix}}{\det(A)}$

Or simply :
$X=\begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{pmatrix} = \frac1{\det(A)} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\det(A_1)\\
\det(A_2)\\
\det(A_3)\end{pmatrix}.$

There is no solution if and only if : $\det(A) = 0$ and $\Big( \det(A_1) \ne 0\quad\text{ou}\quad\det(A_2) \ne 0\quad\text{ou}\quad\det(A_3) \ne 0 \Big)\,$

In the case   $\det(A) = \det(A_1) = \det(A_2) = \det(A_3) = 0$, we can have an infinity of solution or no solution .

In your example, first the matrix is not a scare matrix, so it is already a singe that you can have infinity of solution, under the fact that the number of equation that you have is not the same as the number of variable in your model. This is due to the fact that one variable is consider as parameter.